# C# - Dynamic Keyword and Interface Implementations

Tags: c#, silverlight, .net-4.0, dynamic-keyword

I'm assuming this isn't possible but before digging further is there a way to do something like this:

```
public void ProcessInterface(ISomeInterface obj) {}

//...

dynamic myDyn = GetDynamic<ISomeInterface>() 
ProcessInterface(myDyn);
```

I've seen a [post](http://incrediblejourneysintotheknown.blogspot.com/2009/02/what-wrong-with-c-40-dynamic-keyword.html) arguing for it but it sounds like it wasn't included.

A little context: .Net assembly exposed through COM -> Silverlight app consuming interface-implementing classes. Would be nice to refer to the objects by interface. I really don't expect that this was what was intended...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `dynamic` won't make a type pretend to implement an interface (even if it has, via `dynamic`, all the methods). Passing it to `ProcessInterface` essentially takes away the `dynamic`.

`dynamic` depends on the *calling* code just as much as the implementing object. More, even.

You *could* however make an interface wrapper that uses duck typing:

```
class Foo : IBar {
    readonly dynamic duck;
    public Foo(dynamic duck) { this.duck = duck; }

    void IBar.SomeMethod(int arg) {
        duck.SomeMethod(arg);
    }
    string IBar.SomeOtherMethod() {
        return duck.SomeOtherMethod();
    }
}
interface IBar {
    void SomeMethod(int arg);
    string SomeOtherMethod();
}
```

Comment: That's kind of what I expected. I think whenever my code get hacky ideas like this pop into my head...

Comment: That would sure elevate my hack level...Now to write some code to emit Foo at runtime...

Comment: @Adam - I don't recommend it - those `duck.SomeMethod(arg)` etc calls are **scary** if you look at them in reflector.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I understand your point. If you know the exact interface you're be dealing with, why do you need to use `dynamic`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the opensource [Impromptu-Interface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) to do this. It's an automated way to make a interface wrapper and uses the DLR. `Impromptu.ActLike<ISomeInterface>(myDyn)`